# How to find questions I didn't answer?

Tags: support, questions, search

May be it is trivial, however I try to write query which find questions without my answers, and I fail (so question can already have other peoples answers but not my). This is what I try so far:

```html
select
  q.Id,
  q.Id AS [Post Link],
  q.Tags,
  COUNT(*) as AnsCount2
from
    Posts q
  inner join
    Posts a
  on a.parentId = q.Id
where
      a.OwnerUserId != 860099
  and a.postTypeId = 2
  and q.ClosedDate IS NULL
GROUP BY q.Id, q.Tags
ORDER BY q.Id ASC offset 70 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

My `UserId=860099` When I run above query at offser(row) 72 I get [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38409027/860099) (id=657) - which contains my answer... :( . How to fix it?

Comment: Are you talking about in the search bar on top - as a inverse of user: 346998 ?

Comment: no I ask about query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no search operator supporting this, so you have to resort to e.g. the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1166432/questions-not-answered-by-me?UserId=860099) is an attempt; since its output is limited to 50,000 records you won't find *every* Stack Overflow question you didn't answer.

[image]

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so you might have already answered the question in the meantime. If you're interested, take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1166432) the query to filter e.g. on tags you're interested in.